# How to display user related content in views?

Tags: views

I use drupal 7 and views 3.
I have a view that display list of users.
I want to display for each user related content.

What is the related content? - 
related content is content (node) that it's field 'field_uid' value is equal to the user uid.

How can I do it?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's **not possible** to have relation with a view based on a text field.

I order to achieve that you need to use [entityreference module](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) to create reference field, then it would be possible to use it in view relation.

If you have a custom entity and in [hook_schemah](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_schema/7.x) you create 'foreign key' then views will identify that in relation.

Comment: I don't want to display the user content authored, I want to display the content that the field 'field_uid' value equals to the user uid value.

Comment: What type is that field? entityreference field or normal text field?

Comment: normal text field

Comment: Then that is not possible, views won't understand the field is referred to another entity, you need to convert that field to entity reference field.

Comment: Thank you very much! that what I missed - the entity reference field.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a view listing Content(not User entities);
2. Add your "field_uid" as a relationship;
3. Add "Content: Title" and a "User: Name" marked as a field from the relationship you created earlier check the "Exclude from display".
4. Click on "Settings" in the "Format" section and choose from "Grouping field" your User field added previously.

You should see now your Node title grouped by your User name.

Comment: I didn't find the 'field_uid' in the relationship fields options